# Update query with text extraction

Tags: ms-access

I have 2 tables:

```
T1: ProductID / Product (Ex: 1 = PB 2500MM / 2 = PB 2600MM ...)
T2: PriceID / ProductID / Price
```

So far, so good.
What i am trying to do is to update the price of all the "similar" products (PB products in the example without taking into account the length of the PB)

Thanks for your time!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

That could be:

```sql
Update T2
Set Price = 5.5
Where ProductID In 
    (Select ProductID From T1 
    Where Product Like "PB *")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an UPDATE query with a LIKE operator

```
UPDATE T2
INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.ProductID = T1.ProductID
SET Price = 1.05 * Price
WHERE T1.Product LIKE 'PB*'
```

Note: other databases like Oracle often do not support this way of joining tables in an UPDATE command.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply! The thing is "PB" was just an example. It can be lots of things. I have something like 6000 entries. Some will be unique, others can have up to 10 similar products...

Matt

Comment: Then you must give your products a category field, so that you can filter by category. "Similar" is a very vague description. Also it is not clear what exactly this update consists of.